# I would like to generate a SQL script for stored procedure performance monitoring

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-performance, performance-monitor

We currently have performance issues as I’m sure most data-driven systems do have the same problems.

Currently, they basically fall into 2 categories that I think a single solution can solve:

1. Stored procedures sometimes get automatically recompiled in the system with a bad plan, that causes it to run really slowly. The reason for this is that the set of parameters that it first gets recompiled with are not representative / normal / optimal. This then causes the stored procedure to run really slowly and it needs to be recompiled to pick up a better plan
2. Due to the dynamic nature of how SQL Server works, as a table grows, as different parts of the system maybe query it differently – the indexes need to change or a code change is required to remove sub-optimal coding, like OR’s, functions in WHERE conditions, etc.

Is there any system tables that track the cost of stored procedures?

We need to create a script, that should run for every hour for all the week (7 days) and we need to have/store the data of stored procedure (like execution time, cost of stored procedure and so on). From this, we can identify the list of stored procedures which are performing very worst and running for longer time and generate the list of stored procedures. From that, we can perform tuning on these stored procedures to improve the performance.

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: An example of the sp which get recompiled with a bad execution plan?

Comment: If your SPs run slow, identify the query with the bad plan and add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to it. This should be anticipated during development -. e.g. when depending on parameters, or using tables which will change significatly their statistics over time compared to the time the SP is created (and compiled).

Answer (score 0):

Start here: [sp_BlitzFirst from Brent Ozar Unlimited](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/) or  [BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit on github](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit).

Quoting Kendra Little on her page for [performance monitoring](https://www.littlekendra.com/tag/performance-monitoring/):

> "[It’s only worth it to write your own tools when nobody offers a solution that fits you.](https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/08/25/collect-and-baseline-wait-statistics-dear-sql-dba-episode-14/)"